# How can I assign the "required" statement to one of the Submit buttons in an HTML form?

Tags: html, forms, button, input, submit

I have an HTML form with two submit inputs. One of them resets the application form, and the other one proceeds to the next levels:

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
<input type="text" name="username" value="" required aria-required="true">
<input type="submit" name="info" value="Next Step">
<input type="submit" name="info" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Now i have used the "required" tag that doesn't allow users proceed unless they have filled in the username filed.

Is there any way I can exclude the reset button because the reset button should't need any verification.

One solution I can think of is to put the reset button outside of the form, but I would have some problems with aligning the buttons, because I want both buttons to be in one row and if one of them is inside a DIV tag inside of a form, and with the other one outside of the form, they will never get aligned in one row (I have tried a lot, it doesn't work!).

I wonder if there are any other ways or workarounds to handle this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `formnovalidate` attribute:

```
<input type="submit" name="info" value="Reset" formnovalidate>
```

Browser support is limited, but probably roughly as limited as for the `required` attribute.

Note: The value (button text) “Reset” may be misleading, as it suggests that the button is a so-called reset button, which permanently destroys any data entered in the form but does not cause any server interaction. Such buttons (which should almost never be used, but are commonly used) are typically labeled with “Reset”.

Comment: formnovalidate? Hmm! I hope it works in chrome and FF. Thanks!

Comment: According https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/input it is supported in Chrome from version 10 (with some messy earlier history) and in Firefox from version 4. So the support is good. (IE 9 does not support “HTML5 form validation”, e.g. the `required` and `pattern` attributes, at all.)

Answer (score 2):

Use a `<button type="reset">`, it won't validate.

Comment: Thanks buddy! I'm gonna give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

use `<input type="reset" name="info" value="Reset">`

This will not submit the form. and you can do validation on the `input type="submit"`

Comment: Wow! Never heard of that! I'm gonna give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that both your buttons are included under submit type, which will anyway do a submission on your form. So, you can simply use reset button type as

```
   <input type="reset" name="info" value="Reset">
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! I hope it doesn't need any verification.